# jQuery Animate top - animated element not staying in same position

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Here is my html:

```
<div id = "firstlevel">
    test 
</div>
<div id = "tooltip">
      Tooltip
</div>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$("#firstlevel").hover(function(){
    $("#tooltip").animate({ opacity: 1, top: '-=10px' }, 100);
},
function(){
    $("#tooltip").stop().animate({ opacity: 0, top: '+=10px' }, 100);
});
```

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6gpyhotx/1/

Currently, when you hover quickly back and forth and back and forth over the parent, the tooltip eventually start to shift its position.

When I remove the `.stop()` method, it works well and stays in the same place, however we don't want it to repeat all the time.

I just need the tooltip to stay in the same place and not move lower or higher after many hover overs.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me in Firefox 38.0a2, what browser have you tested in? Same in Chrome 41.0.2272.89.

Comment: can you post screenshots what you expect ?

Comment: I guess working fine in Chrome, position is at the same place when hover

Comment: firefox 35.0
It works fine at first, but to test you have to continue hovering back and forth over the parent - eventually the tooltip position starts to shift

Comment: also if you go really fast over the parent from left to right for example, the tooltip will start to shift to the bottom

Comment: I can't replicate the issues using that fiddle. Tried in Firefox 34.0.5, 35.0.1 & 36.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer a CSS3 animation with a class. It works better and is hardware accelerated.
Add a class to the tooltip on hover, remove it on hover out. Job done!

```js
$("#firstlevel").hover(function(){
    $("#tooltip").addClass('shift');
},
function(){
    $("#tooltip").removeClass('shift');
});
```

```css
#tooltip{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#tooltip.shift{
  transform : translateY(20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstlevel">Hover me</div>

<div id="tooltip">I'm the tooltip</div>
```